# Sharing workspace across multiple computers

Tags: phpstorm

I am trying to use phpStorm on 2 computers to work on a project that is synchronized through dropbox. From what I read it looks like concurrent use of a personal license on multiple computers is supported as of 2015. However, when I save files on each computer, it changes workspace.xml in the .idea folder. This throws the following error when I go to work on the other computer.

"Project Files Changed

Project components were changed externally and cannot be reloaded:

ToolWindowManager

Would you like to reload project?"

How can I fix this problem so I don't have to reload phpStorm every time I save a file?

Comment: that's not recommended way to work with a project. You're basically working over shared project copy? Why don't you close IDE on one of the computers when you go over to another?

Comment: Because I am working on both computers simultaneously, and need to use the IDE on both of them. I imagine this is pretty common, how could multiple developers work on a project without running into this?

Comment: Each developer works with it's own (local) copy of a project. Once some changes to a code are done one either upload changed files to a remote server or pushes commit using version control system

Answer (score 1):

Use git instead of dropbox and commit your changes excluding .idea project files to a branch before you leave one computer.

You could also try to exclude the .idea project files from the dropbox sync folder via symlinks to not have them synced.